# How is 'scrypt' pronounced?

Tags: scrypt

Please help me end this argument.

How is 'scrypt' pronounced?

Could it be pronounced "script"? "Es Crypt"? "skriped"?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a question about English grammar

Comment: This is a question about English pronunciation, not grammar, for a security-related technical term. I wonder if it would be better at the [information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) branch of stackexchange?

Comment: I [cross-posted this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46692/how-is-scrypt-pronounced) to information security.

Comment: It's about the pronunciation of a denotation in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a formal convention. Your best bet is probably to inquire at the inventor, the one-man company tarsnap. Start at [their webpage about scrypt](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html).

Since the important point is cryptographic security and because of their unix-like naming (**tar**snap!), I'd say this probably follows the same convention that makes `ssh` the secure shell. Hence my personal preference is to emphasize it as s(ecure) crypt(ographic grade hash), and hence favor the pronunciation s - crypt, but you see from the sheer amount of parenthesis I need to explain just how individualistic this interpretation may be.

EDIT:
I am feeling somewhat dissatisfied by my own answer, and hence have sought other opinions, even at the risk of committing the sin of cross-posting. It seems to be a difficult question because the technical communities tend to declare language issues off-topic. I sympathize, myself often preferring the technical or logical content over issues of syntax, irrelevant semantic nuances, or indeed pronunciation. Yet [on the English branch of Stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141519/how-are-invented-names-like-scrypt-pronounced-that-include-nonstandard-abbrevi) <s>at least</s> the <s>initial</s> comments go in the direction that the <s>technical</s> community of all the people using `scrypt` as a word decides. This appears to be circular referencing. Hence I don't even know where we could have migrated the question to if we decide it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

The most common pronunciation I have heard is [/skript/](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20script)